# Why can't I read the value outside an observable

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I am new to swift and trying to teach myself how to build and iOS app.  I hooked up the backend to a Firebase Realtime Database and I am able to successfully read and write to the DB but I cannot access the values outside of an observable.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    var test12:String!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        self.ref.child("Title").child("Name").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            self.test12 = snapshot.value! as? String
            print(self.test12!)
        }
        print(self.test12!)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

The first print(self.test12!) prints out correctly so I know I am getting the correct information from there DB, but the second one errors out. How can I use the information I get back from the DB throughout my program?

Comment: The ***first*** print is actually the ***second*** print. `observe` works asynchronously. Do the things you need to do inside the closure. And force downcasting an optional to an optional (`value! as?`) is pointless.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've chosen RTDB over Firestore? I would not perform this work in `viewDidLoad`, and especially not before `super.viewDidLoad()`. It can be a bit early for some interfaces. I would opt for `viewWillAppear()` after calling its super. And I would strongly suggest you safely unwrap database data using `if-let` or `guard`. You can never guarantee the data coming from the network is pure; it may be missing, corrupted, or an unexpected type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason only 1 of your 2 print statements is printing the object is because it's within the asynchronous handler of the `observe` method. The second print statement is called synchronously after `observe` is first called, so it would use `self.test12` before it's been populated.

If you want anymore info on what's going on here - you can look into multi-threading and GrandCentralDispatch.